# How to have AngularJS output escaped HTML

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html-escape-characters

I am getting JSON data from the server, one of the field contains escaped html (an email body actually):

`&lt;html&gt;\r\n&lt;head&gt;\r\n&lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=iso-8859-1&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;/head&gt;\r\n&lt;body dir=&quot;auto&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;div&gt;Buonasera, ho verificato i dati sul mio account ed il numero di cell che vi ho fornito&lt;/div&gt;\r\n&lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;\r\n&lt;a` (more...)

I am getting crazy at trying to render it with AngularJs.

The following is not working:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="mail.htmlbody"></div>
```

Which I believe is normal because the html is in fact escaped.
Should I unescape it first? Is Angular capable of unescaping html with some available service?

If I use $sce like this:

```
scope.mail.htmlbody = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.mail.htmlbody);
```

The source html is displayed, inspecting the element I can see the content is quoted. In other words in the page the source html is displayed instead of the html being rendered. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: why don't you send as proper html from server?

Comment: It's what I resolved doing to make it work. But I thought was safer to transport the html escaped.

Comment: Don't see why it would be any safer, or what difference it would make

Comment: what version of angular are you using? ng-bind-html-unsafe was remove in version 1.2+ in favor of ng-bind-html and $sce service

Comment: @max Favilli - Were you able to fix this issue?? What is the solution?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

At the same time `$sce` service was introduced (angular 1.2), support for `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive was dropped.  The new directive is `ng-bind-html`.  If you use this, the code should work [as documented](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce):

```
 <div ng-bind-html="mail.htmlbody"></div>
```

Comment: what if i dont want rest of inner html not overwritten and can't create span tag for custom text

Answer (score 16):

Use this  directive:

```
<div ng-bind-html="mail.htmlbody"></div>
```

Don't forget to use angular sanitize on your app module.

check here : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: @IlanBiala I'll elaborate. He means to add the ngSanitize module to your app as follows:  angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']); and also include the angular-sanitize.js script from here http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js (or whichever version you want) .. the ng-bind-html won't work without these. Hope that helps anyone visiting here.