# AngularJS render HTML within double curly brace notation

Tags: html, angularjs

I have JSON variables that contain HTML.

By doing: `{{source.HTML}}` Angular is showing `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

What can I do to have Angular render the actual HTML?

**UPDATE:**
This is my controller:

```
app.controller('objectCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    var productId = ($routeParams.productId || "");

    $http.get(templateSource+'/object?i='+productId)
       .then(function(result) {
          $scope.elsevierObject = {};
          angular.extend($scope,result.data[0]);
        });
  }]);
```

Inside my HTML i can then use:

```
<div>{{foo.bar.theHTML}}</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have AngularJS output escaped HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436579/how-to-have-angularjs-output-escaped-html)

Comment: look into [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Hi @Seth it's not a duplicate, this one focusses on the curly brace notation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you want to *show* the HTML (like `<b>Hello</b>`) or *render* the HTML (like **Hello**) ?

- If you want to show it, the curly bracket is enough. However if the html you have has html entities (like `&lt;stuff`) you need to manually unescape it, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480757/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-js-change-lt-to).
- If you want to render it, you need to use the `ng-bind-html` directive instead of curcly bracket (which, FYI, is a shortcut to the `ng-bind` directive). You need to tell Angular that the content injected into that directive is safe, using `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

See example of both cases below:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.HTML = '<b>Hello</b>';
  
  $scope.trust = $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>Show: {{HTML}}</div>
  <div>Render: <span ng-bind-html="trust(HTML)"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html and controller are different. I don't see where you set `$scope.foo.bar.theHTML`. Note that I have updated my answer with more information

Comment: Can't you just use <span ng-bind-html="HTML"/>?

Comment: You can. Just make sure you are referencing ngSanitize.