# Angularjs: render raw html inside double curly braces - possible?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to render raw html snippet inside angular's double curly braces, but couldn't find a way to do it.
I know there's `ng-bind-html` directive for binding raw html text, but this only works inside a tag (I mean it replaces the contents of a tag), but I want to insert a html snippet without enclosing it in any tag.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
    .....
    <div>...</div>

{{</div><div class="row">}}  <- here's what i'd like to insert - close a row and start a next one 

    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
    .....
    <div>...</div>

</div>
```

So, if you look at the html structure above, I want to insert a closing tag and immediately open a new one. This has to be done dynamically, because all the content is dynamic and I would like to divide it into rows depending on the data model.
Any ideas?

Comment: see this link [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444803/angularjs-render-html-within-double-curly-brace-notation) it is same as your question

Comment: That is not a good approach to do such things. Better to use specific components for each one.

Comment: I agree with Jai that it is not a good approach. Maybe you could have to objects and redivide both contents the way you need. If the {{ code }} should not be rendered then first element should have all the items, and if it does split it where you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you wanna do, and I'm very sure, that it's not the best way or even smart, but you can try this:

`{{'</div><div class="row">'}}`

Answer (score 0):

Define one variable in your scope:

```
$scope.rowHtml = "<strong>Your text here</strong>"
```

Assign it to `ng-model` of your `<DIV>`

```
<div class="row" ng-model="rowHtml ">
```