# After using $sce.trustAsHtml, ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to print to the screen custom html using angular. I am using `$sce.trustAsHtml` in combination with `ng-bind-html` to accomplish this. The goal is not only to be able to print this custom html, but that it will retain directives such as ng-click and they will be usuable. Examples I have seen in articles such as follows are promising:

[AngularJS render HTML within double curly brace notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444803/angularjs-render-html-within-double-curly-brace-notation)

However in my implementation I find that although the html renders correctly including references to ng-click, the directive doesn't seem to work anymore when trying to click on the link I am using it on; here is some sample code:

```
$scope.htmlExpression = $sce.trustAsHtml("<a ng-click='test();'>Click Me</a>");

$scope.test = function() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}

<div>
  <p ng-bind-html="htmlExpression"></p>
</div>
```

As everything renders fine and nothing appears lost in translation when analyzing the source; I am left feeling as if I have left something out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to compile it.

Comment: How can I recompile it from within the Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize and bind the html. If this does not work, $digest to reboot the digest cycle.

Comment: I am not familiar with these; is there an example I can reference on how to trigger these?

Comment: yeah https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/ , you retrigger the cycle. For ngSanitize you just need to include the lib into your module.