# How to bind html tags in html using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div><code><pre>{{out_html}}</pre></code></div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.out_html = "<p style='color:red'>John Smith</p>";
```

I want to show that 'p' tag name "John smith" in red color in html browser. But here it's showing html code instead of red color `John Smith.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ivCmO1ZbJWjZvU1j86Dp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user [`ng-bind-html`](https://www.javatpoint.com/angularjs-ng-bind-html-directive) directive for binding a html in angular js,

here is your working [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/VIceJeu0P5yOEpjh)

```
<code>
      <pre>
        <p ng-bind-html="out_html"></p>
      </pre>
</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind it like:

```
<div>
  <code>
    <pre ng-bind-html="out_html" style="color:red;"></pre>
  </code>
</div>
```

For Color you can style `<pre>` element.

The ng-bind-html directive is a secure way of binding content to an HTML element.
For more Details: 
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind-html.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Angular sanitizes binded expressions by default. To prevent that you can use ngBindHtml: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml.

However, if this is just a matter of styling, why don't you use `ngClass` ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your p tag value and p color, just add another variable/scope

**HTML**

```
<div><code><pre><p style='color:{{color}}'>{{value}}</p></pre></code></div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.value = "John Smith";
$scope.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a safety precaution from angularjs. This is to ensure unwanted behaviour.
So Angular will always escape the tags for you. What you can do is use **ng-bind-html** but what's very important is that you first "allow" this string to be interpreted as HTML that works with **trustAsHtml**.

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.out_html = "<p style='color:red'>John Smith</p>";
  $scope.trust = $sce.trustAsHtml;
});

<span ng-bind-html="trust(out_html)"></span></div>
```

Here is also another thread of that problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28444859/8196542